# Request method wallet_switchEthereumChain is not supported

Tags: ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

Code snippet that throws the error:

```
   const { ethereum }: any = window;
   await ethereum.request({
      method: 'wallet_switchEthereumChain',
      params: [{ chainId }],
   });
```

Tried using ethers.js v6:

```
  const ETHERSJS_PROVIDER = new BrowserProvider(ethereum);
  await ETHERSJS_PROVIDER.send('wallet_switchEthereumChain', [
      { chainId },
  ]);
```

Comment: It's likely that the wallet does not support the method. Try with a different wallet.

Comment: It worked before updating ethers.js to version 6. I'm using Metamask wallet extension for testing

Answer (score 3):

When I had the Coinbase extension installed, I found the same error. There appears to be an error with the Coinbase extension.